# Measuring goodness of fit when making a localized average of a function with uncertainty in $x$ and $y$

Tags: estimation, chi-squared-test, optimization, goodness-of-fit, function

I have a function $y=f(x)$ that is defined on the interval $[0, 1]$.

I would like to estimate $y_0=f(x_0)$ at some location $x_0$.

I have a procedure with multiple free parameters $\vec \alpha$ that estimates $y_0 = f(x_0; \vec \alpha)$.

The procedure terminates with estimates $x_0'$ and $y_0'$ as well as $1\sigma$ standard deviations in these quantities, call them $\sigma_y$ and $\sigma_x$.

I want to search for the optimal parameters $\hat \alpha$ that give me the best fit at that location in my function.

My difficulty is in formulating the objective function. Is a good objective function simply

$$
\chi^2(\vec \alpha) = \left( \dfrac{x_0' - x_0}{\sigma_x} \right)^2 + \left( \dfrac{y_0' - y_0}{\sigma_y} \right)^2 
$$

or can I do better?

My worry with this kind of objective function is that it ignores the fact that I am estimating a *function* rather than a single value, and so the behavior of $x_0$ at $x_0'+\sigma_x$ may be drastically different than the behavior at $x_0'$. Another worry is the fact that the $\sigma$s depend on $\vec \alpha$, and so this optimization procedure may choose to inflate $\sigma_x$ and $\sigma_y$ instead of getting good estimates $x_0'$ and $y_0'$.

Any advice?

Comment: What is given? $x_0$? $f(\,\,)$? Where is the uncertainty in these coming from? (Alternatively, where is the partial knowledge coming from?)

Comment: @GeoMatt2 it's a toy problem so I have access to all of the information. In reality I won't know what $f$ truly is but for right now in my toy model I do know $f$. I am trying to "prove the concept" that it is possible to recover $f$ using this procedure.

Comment: OK, but in the "real test" how will $f$ be provided? A set of $(x,y)$ points? A black-box $g[x]=f[x]+\epsilon$? A "low-fidelity" simulator $f_\alpha$ approximating the hi-fi $f=f_\infty$? I am having trouble understanding the context of the toy problem.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 in reality $f$ will never be provided, but in this situation I have $f$ (from a simulation). I am trying to show that for certain values of $\alpha$ a localized measurement of $f$ at a location $x_0$ is possible.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 oh, I guess I am seeing your confusion. I observe a list of values $\vec a$ (previously unmentioned) and I use the procedure to infer $x_0', y_0'$ at the desired location $x_0$ based off of those values.